# bootstrap.sh not found error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, compiling, boost

I tried to install boost on Ubuntu 16.04 and when I run `./bootstrap.sh` the following error happens all the time.

```
samri@samri-Satellite-C55-C:~/boost$ ./bootstrap.sh
./bootstrap.sh: 1: ./bootstrap.sh: ./tools/build/v2/engine/build.sh: not found
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset ... 
Failed to build Boost.Build build engine
Consult 'bootstrap.log' for more details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Boost.Build from the [Boost.Build GitHub webpage](https://github.com/boostorg/build). In this archive `/tools/build/v2/engine/` is replaced by `/tools/build/src/engine`. The .zip archive contains a file named *bootstrap.sh* in the root directory and a tutorial (*tutorial.html*) which is the same as the official Boost.Build tutorial at [Boost.Build tutorial](http://www.boost.org/build/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you clone it from the [GitHub super-project](https://github.com/boostorg/boost)? If so, don't forget to initialise any submodules you need, including *./tools/build*. The easiest thing to do is pull everything:

```sh
cd ~/boost
git submodule update --init
./bootstrap.sh
```